# using django s3 sqlite package for using sqlite db

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am deploying my django app with aws lambda using zappa.
I am trying to store my sqlite db on aws s3-bucket, using django_s3_sqlite (following those instructions: https://github.com/FlipperPA/django-s3-sqlite), but when I run the 'zappa manage [instance] s3_sqlite_vacuum' command, i get this message:
'Task timed out after 30.03 seconds'. Does anyone know this? thank you!

Comment: Since the tasks is timing out after exactly 30 seconds, it seems to be a problem with Zappa reaching AWS. Are you able to perform any other functionality using `zappa manage [instance]`, for example, `collectstatic`?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it might be hitting the zappa lambda function timeout limit, one can set "timeout_seconds": 300 in the zappa_settings.json which will allow the lambda to run for longer.

Thank you FlipperPA for the django-s3-sqlite package!